# Is there away to retrieve results (including found vulnerabilities) of a specific scan from one API call?

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, api, vulnerability-management

Is there away to retrieve results (including found vulnerabilities) of a specific scan from one API call?
From InsightVm documentation, the GET scan API call returns only scan info with statistics of the found vulnerabilities, without information of the found vulnerabilities.
From what I understood I have to do another GET vulnerability API call to retrieve the found vulnerability by passing the identifier of the vulnerability which is not returned by the scan results API call. 
From my experience with Nessus, it was possible to retrieve scan results with found vulnerabilities of a specific scan or for all scans from one API call.

Comment: Are you asking about how to use the InsightVM API specifically? If so, you need to look up its documentation and work with Rapid7 support.